# SQL Server : copy a table into another table in reverse order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that newer data starts with `id=1` and increasing the `id`, we get to the older data, now the problem is, as new data will be added every day, and I want to show the results from new to old, there will be a problem. I want to reverse the order of the table that even after new data are added I can display the data from newer to older one.

Has anyone any clue what should I do?

Comment: Don't change the table, if you really want to order by the id just use the order by clause in your sql: select * from table order by id desc

Comment: @jrdn: But OP's problem is that he cannot order by id since id 1 was newest until now, but now new data will get a higher id.

Comment: Tables in SQL Server **never** have an order per se - you **only** get an order when you select from a table and specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hard-code the arbitrary number where the switch-over happens.  Say you have 1,000 rows in there right now (so #1 is the newest, but #1001 will be the newest when it's added):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN id < 1000 THEN id * -1 ELSE id END) AS sort_order
ORDER BY sort_order DESC
```

Probably the better solution would be to add a timestamp column, as it's not nice to rely on auto-generated columns for real data.

**Edit**

To create a new table, use the above with an insert.

```
INSERT INTO [new_table] (col1,col2,col3, ...)
SELECT (col1, col2, col3, ...)
FROM [old_table]
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN id < 1000 THEN id * -1 ELSE id END) DESC
```

Comment: As I have not set up my website. I want to just create a new table with my desired order rather than splitting table into 2 parts. I just don't know how to copy this table to another but in reverse order.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani then simply create a copy of your table, and use the above query to select into the new table... see my update

Comment: I used your code but with a little change as i don't want negative Id .  `INSERT INTO [new_table] (col1,col2,col3, ...)
SELECT (col1, col2, col3, ...)
FROM [old_table]
ORDER BY id DESC`  this did exactly what I wanted. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to add a `datetime` field to you table.

However, your ID is not usable as order field directly since until now ID=1 was newest but from now on every new record will get a higher ID than X. So you need to identify X which is the ID value of the oldest record until now. Then you can order by two cases:

- belongs it to the **low-id=new** or  to the **high-id=new** group?

Here's an example where `X=10`:

```
    SELECT ID 
    FROM dbo.tbl
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID <=10 THEN ID ELSE -ID END ASC
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95c9a/3/0

---

> but i want to copy the content to a new table so that i won't need to
>   treat them differently

Then you can use the sql above to insert into the new table in that order. I would use a new `ID` column with `IDENTITY(1,1)`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCopy
  SELECT ID 
  FROM dbo.tbl
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID <=10 THEN ID ELSE -ID END ASC
```

If you don't want to add another column and you want to reuse the old id, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` with above `CASE`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCopy
  SELECT ID = 
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID <=10 THEN ID ELSE -ID END ASC)
  FROM dbo.tbl
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00213/1/0

Comment: but i want to copy the content to a new table so that i won't need to treat them differently. I want help with copying it. this is my temp table

Comment: So why not using my sql above to insert in that order? Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: when I execute this :  `INSERT INTO sms2
  SELECT ID = 
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID <=30000 THEN ID ELSE -ID END ASC)
  FROM sms` i get the error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: So what _is_ your table definition?? If you have other columns you need to select these too.